# Print full sequence not just first line | Python 3.3 | Print from specific line to end (")

Tags: python, parsing, sequence

I am attempting to pull out multiple (50-100) sequences from a large .txt file seperated by new lines ('\n'). The sequence is a few lines long but not always the same length so i can't just print lines x-y. The sequences end with " and the next line always starts with the same word so maybe that could be used as a keyword.

I am writing using python 3.3

This is what I have so far:

```
searchfile = open('filename.txt' , 'r')

cache = [] 
for line in searchfile:
    cache.append(line)

for line in range(len(cache)):
    if "keyword1" in cache[line].lower():
        print(cache[line+5])
```

This pulls out the starting line (which is 5 lines below the keyword line always) however it only pulls out this line.

How do I print the whole sequence?

Thankyou for your help.

EDIT 1:

Current output =  ABCDCECECCECECE ...

Desired output = ABCBDBEBSOSO ...

```
             ABCBDBDBDBDD ...

             continued until " or new line
```

Edit 2

Text file looks like this:

```
Name (keyword):
Date
Address1
Address2
Sex
Response"................................" 
Y/N
```

The sequence between the " and " is what I need

TL;DR -  How do I print from line + 5 to end when end = keyword

Comment: `print(cache[line:line + 5])` maybe?

Comment: I am afraid it didn't work thankyou though

Comment: Can you add a shortened version of what the text file is supposed to look like?

Comment: GIven that you want to start at line+5 to the end wounld `print(cache[line+5:])` work to extend the slice to the end?

Comment: it only prints line 5 rather than the next few lines as the problem is they are treated as seperate lines because of the array format

Comment: I was hoping I could print from line+5 to end = " maybe but have no idea how to make that work

Answer (score 0):

1This can be done rather simply with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re

lines = 'Name (keyword):','Date','Address1','Address2','Sex','Response"................................" '
for line in lines:
    match = re.search('.*?"(:?.*?)"?',line)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Eventually to use this sample code we would `lines = f.readlines()` from the dataset. Its important to note that we catch only things between `"` and  another `"`, if there is no " mark at the end, we will miss this data, but accounting for that isn't too difficult.

Comment: I got: NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be line and `file` is the file path/text name

Comment: I have simplified the code to show how it would work based upon your sample file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your sequence data but if you're searching for each 'keyword' then the next " char then the following should work:

```
keyword_pos =[]
endseq_pos = []
for line in range(len(cache)):
    if 'keyword1' in cache[line].lower():
        keyword_pos.append(line)
    if '"' in cache[line]:
        endseq_pos.append(line)

for key in keyword_pos:
    for endseq in endseq_pos:
        if endseq > key:
            print(cache[key:endseq])
            break
```

This simply compiles a list of all the positions of all the keywords and " characters and then matches the two and prints all the lines in between.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The code seems to run fine but wont print so I can't check the output any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Michal Frystacky that regex is the way forward.  However as I now understand the problem, we need two searches one for the 'keyword' then again 5 lines on, to find the 'sequence'

This should work but may need the regex to be tweaked:

```
import re

with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    #first search for keyword
    key_match = re.search(r'\((keyword)',line)
    if key_match:
        #if successful search 5 lines on for the string between the quotation marks
        seq_match = re.search(r'"([A-Z]*)"',lines[i+5])
        if seq_match:
            print(key_match.group(1) +' '+ seq_match.group(1))
```

Comment: The code runs well but there is no printout for the output any suggestions

Comment: @M.Smith12 if you are using python 2.7 try removing the brackets around the print function i.e. print key_match.....

Comment: @M.Smith12 looks like a RegEx problem then.  If can post a full unformated sample of say first 6 lines, then I may be able to help adjust the search string for you.